# Why do I lose control over my comments after the question gets migrated?

Tags: support, comments, migration

My question got migrated from [Skeptics](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/27655/can-all-your-public-files-on-dropbox-be-accessed-by-anyone-with-one-of-the-links) to [Information Security](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/88881/can-all-your-public-files-on-dropbox-be-accessed-by-anyone-with-one-of-the-links).
When it was at Skeptics I had commented:

> How is this better? I am changing it.

After the migration, I commented:

> Ah! Migrated! Good.

But Even after logging in and associating the accounts on both the site, I can't delete my original comment.

---

**The new one(has a cross mark):**
[image: new comment]

---

**The old one has gone blank:**
[image: old comment]

What to do? Is it a bug? Should I just comment for deletion? Is there a need to change this?

Comment: I [migrated this post](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/90263/network-mac-address-conversion-to-ipv6-link-local-address) and had no problem deleting my comment on it (I replaced it with another comment on the target site). In other words: *could not reproduce*.

Comment: Then again, I *already* had an account on the target site, so perhaps this has more to do with your account not yet existing on Information Security.

Comment: Ah, known bug, I duped you to it.

Comment: Yes. I made an account on Information Security after it was migrated. @MartijnPieters

Comment: Ah! That was a speedy solution @MartijnPieters. Thanks. I guess I missed this dupe because I didn't use the keyword "ownership".